# Node.js + Express + SQL

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

I want to do the following and I do not know if it's possible to do it.

I have all my queries inside a file like variables, example:

**myQuerys.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var qry_customers = "SELECT * FROM customers";

module.exports = {
    "qry_customers ": qry_customers
};
```

In my *customer.js* I do the connection to database and I do the query, without problems.

**What I want:** Pass a variable (for example: `CustomerID`) to the query. Something like this:

**MyQuery.js**

```
var express = require('express'); 
var router = express.Router();

var qry_customers = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id = " +  **@CustomerID**;

module.exports = {      
    "qry_customers ": qry_customers 
};
```

**Customer.js**

```
//connection to the DB

req.query(qrys.qry_customers + @CustomerID)
```

Is it possible?

I know I can do, and it works:

```
 req.query(qrys.qry_customers + " WHERE id = " + **@CustomerID**)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this with a function that takes an input:

```
module.exports.someQuery = function(id) {
  return "SELECT something from somewhere where id =" +id;
}
```